# SQL Server 2012 -- loop keys

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I have written a query which left joins separate tables and attempts to discover at a point in time (the point of insertion) which PK keys are the newest in a db for a given record.
you will see i have pared it back to patientid 100 as this is the only way  i can seem to get it working.

The current query works as shown:

```
SELECT TOP 1 P1.PatientID, 
             P1.DimPatientPK, 
             DA1.DimAdmissionPK, 
             DD1.DiagnosisPK, 
             DI1.Investigation1PK, 
             DIE1.InvestigationECGPK, 
             IEG1.InvestigationEchoGoldPK, 
             MH1.DimMedicalHistoryPK, 
             FH1.DimPatientFamilyHistoryPK, 
             PHT1.PatientHospitalisationTreatmentPK, 
             PMP1.PatientMedicalPersonnelPK, 
             RR1.PatientReferralReasonPK, 
             PEA1.PhysicalExamAHSPK, 
             PEM1.PhysicalExamMurmursPK, 
             SI1.SocialIssuePK, 
             TRT.TreatmentPK
--DT1.Treatment1PK          
  FROM
       DimPatient P1 LEFT JOIN DimAdmission DA1 ON P1.PatientID = DA1.PatientID
                     LEFT JOIN DimDiagnosis DD1 ON P1.PatientID = DD1.PatientID
                     LEFT JOIN DimInvestigation1 DI1 ON P1.PatientID = DI1.PatientID
                     LEFT JOIN DimInvestigationECG DIE1 ON P1.PatientID = DIE1.PatientId
                     LEFT JOIN DimInvestigationECHOgold IEG1 ON P1.PatientID = DIE1.PatientId
                     LEFT JOIN DimMedicalHistory MH1 ON P1.PatientID = MH1.PatientId
                     LEFT JOIN DimPatientFamilyHistory FH1 ON P1.PatientId = FH1.PatientID
                     LEFT JOIN DimPatientHospitalisationTreatment PHT1 ON P1.PatientID = PHT1.PatientId
                     LEFT JOIN DimPatientMedicalPersonnel PMP1 ON P1.PatientID = PMP1.PatientId
                     LEFT JOIN DimPatientReferralReason RR1 ON P1.PatientID = RR1.PatientId
                     LEFT JOIN DimPhysicalExamAHS PEA1 ON P1.PatientId = PEA1.PatientId
                     LEFT JOIN DimPhysicalExamination PE1 ON P1.PatientID = PE1.PatientId
                     LEFT JOIN DimPhysicalExamMurmurs PEM1 ON P1.PatientID = PEM1.PatientId
                     LEFT JOIN DimSocialIssue SI1 ON P1.PatientID = SI1.PatientID
                     LEFT JOIN DimTreatment TRT ON P1.PatientID = TRT.PatientId
  WHERE P1.patientid IN(100)
  ORDER BY DA1.DimAdmissionPK DESC, 
           P1.DimPatientPK DESC, 
           DD1.DiagnosisPK DESC, 
           DI1.Investigation1PK DESC, 
           DIE1.InvestigationECGPK DESC, 
           IEG1.InvestigationEchoGoldPK DESC, 
           MH1.DimMedicalHistoryPK DESC, 
           FH1.DimPatientFamilyHistoryPK DESC, 
           PHT1.PatientHospitalisationTreatmentPK DESC, 
           PMP1.PatientMedicalPersonnelPK DESC, 
           RR1.PatientReferralReasonPK DESC, 
           PEA1.PhysicalExamAHSPK DESC, 
           PE1.PhysicalExaminationPK DESC, 
           PEM1.PhysicalExamMurmursPK DESC, 
           SI1.SocialIssuePK DESC, 
           TRT.TreatmentPK DESC;
```

This successfully recovers a full record whether it has been filled out or not for the patid 100.

I am having trouble expanding this so that it loops through and collects the same results for every patient in the db.

i.e. if i remove the where clause, i only get 1 row still ..

if i remove select top 1 .. then it returns me multiple sets of patientid 90 - i basically want 1 row for each patientID - ie 90, 91, 92 with the corresponding maximum key value from each table matched.

Anyone have any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: have you tried using the `GROUP BY` clause?

Comment: Just to confirm do you have multiple records for the same patient in your DimPatient table i.e duplicates ?

Answer (score 0):

One (or more) tables you are joining is empty. Change your joins to left outer join, i.e.

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN DimAdmission DA1    ON P1.PatientID = DA1.PatientID
```

for all joined tables. The empty table will have Nulls in the results set columns.

If multiple selections for the same patient ID exist, then one or more of your tables has more than one record for each patient ID. You either need to exclude these tables from the query or look at your data structure and see if there is a field which will let you select single record.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you add the ROW_NUMBER function into your WHERE clause, e.g.

```
    WHERE ROW_NUMBER() (PARTION BY P1.patientid ORDER BY DA1.DimAdmissionPK desc,
P1.DimPatientPK desc, ... ) = 1
```

By "..." I mean move your entire ORDER BY clause inside the ROW_NUMBER function.

Good luck - it seems you are missing a Fact table ...